# Is this identity involving Stirling numbers of the first kind well-known?

Tags: combinatorics, reference-request, stirling-numbers

I've been looking in vain (most books I came across give identities involving sums or recurrence relations, but do not give much attention to fixed values) for a reference to the following identity:
$$S(n,n-3)={n \choose 2}{n \choose 4},$$
where $S(n,k)$ is the unsigned [Stirling number of the first kind](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_first_kind). Is this well-known, or too trivial to be mentioned anywhere?

Comment: It's not trivial, but the constant, 3, is just big enough not to be  important enough to be even an exercise in a text. But it's perfect for OEIS as noted below.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The identity and the proof for the identity are there in the [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_first_kind#Simple_identities) link you have sent.

Comment: Oh hell, so much for being careful. I must have missed it the last time I actually visited the page. Thanks.

Comment: Also noted at [OEIS A001303](http://oeis.org/A001303) which has other formulae and several references to the sequence